# reverse linked list in C using recursion

Tags: c, linked-list

I have written following code in C. I am pretty new to C. The insert and Print functions seem to work fine but I get a prompt that says program stopped working when I call Reverse function. 
Where dis I go wrong ?

```
//WAP to reverse a Linked List using recursion

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* head;  //global variable

struct Node* Reverse(struct Node* p){
    if(p->next == NULL){  //since for last node link part is null
        head = p;
        printf("break condition");
        return head;
    }
    printf("calling reverse");
    Reverse(p->next);
    struct Node* q = p->next;
    q->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;
}

void Insert(int x){
    struct Node* temp= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    //temp->next = NULL; //redundant
    //if(head!= NULL){
    temp->next = head;  //temp.next will point to null when head is null nd otherwise what head was pointing to
    //}
    head = temp;
}

void Print(){
    struct Node* temp1 = head;  //we dont want tomodify head so store it in atemp. bariable and then traverse
    while(temp1 != NULL){
        printf(" %d", temp1->data);
        temp1= temp1->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    Insert(2);
    Insert(4);
    Insert(5);
    Insert(1);
    Print();
    head = Reverse(head);
    //  Print();
}
```

Comment: You may want to start by using the `Reverse` return value for *something*. Right now the `head` assignment in `main()` has no determinate value and your program invokes undefined behavior because all but the last-recursed `Reverse` call performs no `return` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with the program above:

1) You have two `head` variables. One is a global variable, and the other is a variable local to the `main` function. That local variable is the one that is passed to `Reverse()`. Since the first thing that function does is dereferencing it, the program crashes. Removing the local `head` variable in the `main()` function should address it.

2) The `Reverse()` function correctly returns `head` when it reaches the exit condition, but what happens the rest of the time? It's missing a return in the non-exit condition case. Here's a diff that would address the issue:

```
    printf("calling reverse");
-   Reverse(p->next);
+   struct Node* ret;
+   ret = Reverse(p->next);
    struct Node* q = p->next;
    q->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;
+   return ret;
```

Comment: I still have q query though. What really is the use of returning something in non exit condition ? How does that make any difference in this example?head as a global variable was modified in exit condition and hence we returned it but what it the use of returning rest of the times?

Comment: The calls to `Reverse()` are recursive. That means that the first call to `Reverse()` calls `Reverse()` which calls `Reverse()` etc.. until the exit condition is reached. When it is reached the last function returns `head`, which will cause all successive functions to return `head` until it is returned to the original caller. If you want my opinion, I think that that part is unnecessary in your program, since the head is stored in a global variable anyway.